# How do I fetch multiple variables like var1,var2,.. in view page using loop in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

**1.**

In controller I have code like

**2.**

```
foreach($data['response']['data'] as $r) {
        $data['members'.$i] = $this->facebook->api( '/'.$r['id'].'/members');
         $i++;
    }
$this->load->view('index',$data);
```

**3.**

In view page I need value of member1,member2...upto membern.. but I could not understand how to get them. If any other way is there then tell me. Also I am sending the no of groups in $data. I want to see groupname(No of members).

Comment: Arrays are your friends - you would iterate on them, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$data['members'.$i] = $this->facebook->api( '/'.$r['id'].'/members');
```

Into:

```
$data['members'][] = $this->facebook->api( '/'.$r['id'].'/members');
```

Also, you can now get rid of:

```
$i++;
```

And in your view:

```
foreach($members as $value)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    echo print_r($value, true);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am thinking that there is some better way. It's out of mind. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I could probably show you a better way if you could show me the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->facebook->api( '/'.$r['id'].'/members'), true).'</pre>';` but just fill it in with dummy data. The structure is what would be important to me.

Comment: I am not showing the array of members. I am just counting the number of members in each group. I am done with that. No issue remaining. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeIgniter documentation includes a section titled Generating Query Results which has some examples of what you are looking for.

Here's an (obviously contrived) example:

model:

```
class Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_data()
    {
        return $this->db->query('...');
    }
}
```

controller:

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['query_result'] = $this->model->get_data();
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
}
```

view:

```
<?php foreach ($query_result->result() as $row): ?>
    <?php echo $row->field_1; ?>
    <?php echo $row->field_2; ?>
    <?php // and so on... ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Try this.

Comment: I don't want to write as field1,field2..like this way. No way thanks for your idea.